# jQuery select the same OPTION on three SELECT drop downs with one action

Tags: jquery

I have 3 SELECT drop down

SELECT 1

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

SELECT 2

```
<select type="hidden">
  <option value="Sadan">Volvo</option>
  <option value="Sadan">Saab</option>
  <option value="Sport">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Sport">Audi</option>
</select>
```

SELECT 3

```
<select>
  <option value="1000">Sport</option>
  <option value="2000">Sadan</option>
</select>
```

SELECT 2 is hidden in the background (This is due to the JSP/Struts limitation).

What I need is a way if the user selects SELECT 1 option that SELECT 2 corresponding option would be selected and then SELECT 3 corresponding option would be selected.

EXAMPLE:

User selects SELECT 1 option **`<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>`**

EXPECTED RESULTS:

SELECT 2 auto selected option **`<option value="Sport">Mercedes</option>`**

AND

SELECT 3 auto selected option **`<option value="1000">Sport</option>`**

Comment: Did you take a look at the example I put on there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty much it. I'll work up an example.

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
   $('#select2').val($('#select1').val());
   $('#select3').val($('#select2').val());
});
```

**Edit:** The example: http://jsbin.com/ahema

And TStamper has a very good point, make sure you put in the ID, or it won't work. (you can see that in the example)

```
<select --> id="select2" <-- type="hidden">
  <option value="Sadan">Volvo</option>
  <option value="Sadan">Saab</option>
  <option value="Sport">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Sport">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Phil- just to note: that you need to make your select tag the id name posed by your jquery code

Comment: hmm for some reason I can't get it to work. I do have the Id's set for the SELECT but nothing happens

Comment: Did you take a look at the example?

Comment: Yeah I looked at the example and it's the same code that you posted, don't know whats wrong :( I will work on getting it working or posting the problem, thanks

Comment: You should set it up within document.read() or $(function() {...})

Comment: @Phill Pafford - I think that the reason why this wouldn't work also is because in the first select the value attribute doesn't contain the capital letter (<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>) - you can write "Volvo" instead of "volvo". (And the same for the other options)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to 'Group' the corresponding options and then upon selection select those options with a JQuery selector.  From there you could set the select boxes to the desired index.