# Why doesn't attr(attributeName, value) create a new Attr object in the DOM attributes NamedNodeMap?

Tags: jquery, attributes, attr

I can change the value attribute of a HTMLOptionElement by doing so:

```
sizeOptionToBeSelected.attr('value', '555');
```

It changes the value property of the HTMLOptionElement and the value in the DOM Attr object in the NamedNodeMap attributes property from the same HTMLOptionElement object.

But, **I cannot create a new Attr "selected" or change the selected property of the HTMLOptionElement with the following code**:

```
sizeOptionToBeSelected.attr('selected', 'true');
```

**Why do you think this is? How can I do this?**

From jquery documentation:

> We can **add** an attribute the same
>   way:
>       $('#greatphoto').attr('title', 'Photo by Kelly Clark');

Additional explanations:
- The code runs inside the $(document).ready( function so there is no problem with the loading.
- I use the latest Google Chrome 8.0.552.215 beta.

Kind Regards,
Despot

Comment: Although I resolved how jQuery's attr method works, maybe it is a good idea to provide some clue as to why I was trying to do this (I think it is going to be useful for other users).   
I deleted all the options from a select tag and I populated with new ones. And the idea was to make the previously selected option, selected again.   
The right way to do this is: $('#selectId').val(theSelectedOptionValue);  
For more, view this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927656/jquery-select-the-same-option-on-three-select-drop-downs-with-one-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery, somewhat confusingly, tends to treat attributes and properties as the same thing. So `$(elem).attr('selected', true)` is actually setting `elem`'s `selected` property to true, not its attribute.

There are very few reasons to need to set the `selected` *attribute*. Setting the `selected` (and `defaultSelected`) *properties* should suffice.

Also, bear in mind that the `selected` *attribute* corresponds to the default state, not the current state.

Comment: I also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953028/any-diffrence-between-element-setattribute-elementattr-element-attr before I posted. I should have figured out that jQuery cannot create the Attr DOM object.  
Another thing is that jQuery's statement "We can add an attribute the same way: $('#greatphoto').attr('title', 'Photo by Kelly Clark');" isn't correct. Should only say, "change" or "set", but not "add an attribute". This created confusion for me.  
Thanks anyway.