# Change options in selects

Tags: jquery

i'm learning ruby (RoR 4.2.5, ruby 2.1.5)and I need to do 2 selects, the first one is for users and the second one is for discounts

SELECT 1

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">Person1</option>
  <option value="2">Person2</option>
  <option value="3">Person3</option>
  <option value="4">Person4</option>
</select>
```

SELECT 2

```
<select id="select2">
 <option value="100">1</option>
 <option value="200">2</option>
 <option value="50">3</option>
 <option value="20">4</option>
</select>
```

If you select "Person1" select2 needs to be "1" with value "100", with "Person2" select2 needs to be "2" with value "200".
Any idea?

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: It's something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927656/jquery-select-the-same-option-on-three-select-drop-downs-with-one-action
The id of the first one is used like option in Select2

Comment: What to do with Ruby or RubyOnRails? It's a jQuery thing.

Comment: How can I use that kind of jQuery?

Comment: What the heck is `<select type="hidden">`? If the second `select` isn't visible, why use a `<select>` at all?

Comment: @Santi, sorry, my bad

Comment: _If you select "Person1" select2 needs to be "1" with value "100", with "Person2" select2 needs to be "2" with value "200"._ - and when person 3 or 4 are selected - take no action? Because otherwise, if 3 means 50 and 4 means 20 - then you'd be sending rather redundant data; plus it would be easy to manipulate for the user (submit the form with let's say person 4 and 100.) So in that case, the association between person and discount should rather be maintained server-side.

Comment: Wasn't ridiculing, legitimately curious. Is the second select solely just for storing whatever was selected in the first? Why not just make the values of the first select "100", "200", "50", "20"?

Comment: @Santi I'm trying to do something like a dependent combobox, if the value of the first select change the other selects will change as well, using the id of Select1. And I also need the ID of Select1 stored in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are always in synch as far as order goes you can just check for index and then set the second one accordingly.

```
var option_index = $("#select1 option:selected").index();
```

and then you can set the second based on the first index. `$('#select2 option').eq(option_index).prop('selected', true);`

of course you need to initialize and then also listen to the on change event.

Here is more of a complete example of how the JS would be (using **jQuery**):

```
//Initialize on ready:
var option_index = $("#select1 option:selected").index();
$('#select2 option').eq(option_index).prop('selected', true);

//Listen for the change
$('#select1').on('change', function(){
    option_index = $("#select1 option:selected").index();
    $('#select2 option').eq(option_index).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: Jquery it's used in .coffee files, or can be used in the views?

Comment: Typically your scripts would indeed go in the views. Typically you have a shared template for your layout in ROR. I would include the jquery lib just above the end body tag of your layout template to make it avail to all your views.

Comment: Thank you, It works fine on my app